# Is it possible to have static touchpad scrolling speed?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, scrolling

I'm using an Elan touchpad.

However, when I scroll fast with my fingers, the scrolling accelerates as well. Scrolling the same distance slowly, will only scroll a bit.

I wish that the scrolling doesn't depend on my touch speed, but depends on the location I move to (like on a Mac touchpad).

Due to this, I have to put it to the minimum scroll speed to make it feel more "natural", but then again it is a problem with bigger documents.

Is there any way to make the scrolling speed static, instead of depending on my fingers speed over the same distance?

Comment: Speaking as the less-than-happy owner of a 'kinetic scroll' Logitech with no off-switch, I wish you luck ;)

Comment: Touch pads on windows are difficult to get right!

I found one thing that helps make it better (but not static): in the Elan drivers, go to registry, set `ElanTech/SmartPadDisplay/GestureEffect_Display` to `1`. Then open Elan, go to additional -> gesture effect -> select ZoomPerfect. Scrolls more like a touchscreen, in a more controlled and stable manner.